# If the solution dosen't exist, does it mean that problem is not well-posed?

Tags: terminology

A well-posed problem is defined as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem).

If that is so, then does it mean that the solution/s of any over-determined or under-determined system is NOT well-posed?

Similarly, if the solution doesn't exist of any initial value or boundary value problem, does it mean that problem is not well-posed?

Perplexed !

Comment: for a problem to be well-posed all the three conditions need to be satisfied

Answer (score 2):

Since it violates 1) A solution exists (A SOLUTION NEEDN'T EXIST HERE!), this problem is not well-posed.